# Getting routes to handle static content types that produce 404s

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404, static-content

I have an MVC site which is replacing an old website. I want to be able to handle requests for the old static html files but redirect to the 404 error handler on my MVC site - I'd also like to provide a 301 code instead of a 404 to let the crawlers know that the content has moved

At the moment when I try and navigate to static content I get the IIS 404 error. I can use the custom error handling to handle the missing file but I'm not sure I like the way this is working

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="http://localhost/site/Error/NotFound" responseMode="Redirect"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Is there a better way to do this or is this the way that everyone else is doing it? How do I provide a 301 instead of a 404 since it's the static file handler that's serving the content?

Is there a way to get MVC to handle requests for certain file extensions and catch 404s from these if they don't exist?